# $a,b,c$ are non-negative number such that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=1$.Prove $\sqrt{ab(a+b)}+\sqrt{bc(b+c)}+\sqrt{ca(c+a)}\geq\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $a$,$b$,$c$ are non-negative numbers such that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=1$.
> show that $$\sqrt{ab(a+b)}+\sqrt{bc(b+c)}+\sqrt{ca(c+a)}\geq\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}$$

I can't guess where the constant $\sqrt[3]{2}$ come from.

Comment: where come from?

Comment: @math110:If you mean its source, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $ x=b+c,y=a+c,z=a+b,\implies xyz=1,a = min${$a,b,c$}$,a=\dfrac{y+z-x}{2} \ge 0 \implies x \le y+z$

$1=xyz \le x\left(\dfrac{y+z}{2}\right)^2 \le \dfrac{(y+z)^3}{4} \implies y+z \ge \sqrt[3]{4} \implies 2a+b+c \ge \sqrt[3]{4} $

RHS$=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{4}(ab+bc+ca)} \le \sqrt{(2a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}=\sqrt{bc(b+c)+(2a^2b+2a^2c+4abc+ab^2+ac^2)} $

$\sqrt{ab(a+b)}+\sqrt{ca(c+a)}\ge \sqrt{2(ab(a+b)+ca(c+a))}  \iff \sqrt{2(ab(a+b)+ca(c+a))} +\sqrt{bc(b+c)} \ge \sqrt{bc(b+c)+(2a^2b+2a^2c+4abc+ab^2+ac^2)}\iff  ab^2+ac^2 +2\sqrt{2(ab(a+b)+ca(c+a))bc(b+c)} \ge 4abc$

$ab^2+ac^2 \ge 2abc \iff \sqrt{2(ab(a+b)+ca(c+a))bc(b+c)} \ge abc \iff abc(2b^3+2ac^3+2ab^2+2ac^2+3abc) \ge 0$

all above "=" hold when $a=0,b=c$ must be hold both or either. so the inequality will be hold "=" when $a=0$ and $b=c$

QED.

Comment: You use $\sqrt{ab(a+b)}+\sqrt{ca(c+a)}\ge \sqrt{2(ab(a+b)+ca(c+a))} $ that is $\sqrt{u + v} \ge \sqrt{2(u + v)}$. It should be reversed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x := ab(a + b), y := bc(b + c), z := ca(c + a)$.
We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z} \ge \sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{ab + bc + ca}. \tag{1}$$

After squaring both sides, it suffices to prove that
$$x + y + z + 2\sqrt{xy} + 2\sqrt{yz} + 2\sqrt{zx} \ge \sqrt[3]{4}\,(ab + bc + ca). \tag{2}$$

Using AM-GM, we have
$$2\sqrt{xy} + 2\sqrt{yz} + 2\sqrt{zx}
\ge 3\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{xy} \cdot 2\sqrt{yz} \cdot 2\sqrt{zx}}
= 6(abc)^{2/3} \ge 6abc \tag{3}$$
where we use $xyz = a^2b^2c^2(a + b)(b + c)(c + a) = a^2b^2c^2$
and $abc < 1$ (using $(a + b)(b + c)(c + a) \ge 2\sqrt{ab}\cdot 2\sqrt{bc} \cdot 2\sqrt{ca} = 8abc$).

From (2) and (3), it suffices to prove that
$$ab(a + b) + bc(b + c) + ca(c + a) + 6abc \ge \sqrt[3]{4}\,(ab + bc + ca). \tag{4}$$

We have some proofs of (4).
Here we prove (4) using chenbai's nice idea.

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$. We have
\begin{align*}
 (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)
 &\le (a + b)\cdot \frac{(b + c + c + a)^2}{4}\\
 &= (a + b)\cdot \frac{(a + b + 2c)^2}{4}\\
 &\le (a + b + 2c)^3/4
\end{align*}
which results in $a + b + 2c \ge \sqrt[3]{4}$.

It suffices to prove that
$$ab(a + b) + bc(b + c) + ca(c + a) + 6abc \ge (a + b + 2c)(ab + bc + ca)$$
or
$$c(2ab - bc - ca) \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.